Shopware 6.6 - CMS Resolver
I have a custom CMS Resolver with demo data. First, i use shopware 6.5, everything works fine. I updated to shopware 6.6. If i drag & drop my CMS Element, the data of the content (with my defined cms resolver type) doesnt show.
Is there a not documented change for the cms resolver (shopware 6.5 to shopware 6.6) ?
In my console i have the following error:
app.js?1725361876:79 An error was captured in current module: TypeError: _filter_asset is not a function
    at Proxy.render (eval at AZ (app.js?1725361876:43:411), <anonymous>:50:14)
    at nj (app.js?1725361876:39:174753)
    at eO.fn (app.js?1725361876:39:210999)
    at eO.run (app.js?1725361876:39:161136)
    at X.e.update (app.js?1725361876:39:211402)
    at X (app.js?1725361876:39:211428)
    at Z (app.js?1725361876:39:209524)
    at W (app.js?1725361876:39:209299)
    at x (app.js?1725361876:39:206117)
    at eO.fn (app.js?1725361876:39:210450)

Maybe this could be the reason why a drag & drop custom component will not be shown in the administration? Or other issue in shopware 6.6?
My code for the resolver is the following (only demo data)
class ProductTestCmsElementResolver extends AbstractCmsElementResolver
{
public function getType(): string
{
return 'product-test';
}

    public function collect(CmsSlotEntity $slot, ResolverContext $resolverContext): ?CriteriaCollection
    {
        return null;
    }
    
    public function enrich(CmsSlotEntity $slot, ResolverContext $resolverContext, ElementDataCollection $result): void
    {
        $data = new ProductListingStruct();
        $slot->setData($data);
    
        // Ersetze die tatsächlichen Daten durch Demo-Daten
        $demoProducts = [
            [
                'id' => Uuid::randomHex(),
                'name' => 'Demo Produkt 1',
                'price' => '19.99',
                'manufacturer' => 'Demo Hersteller 1',
            ],
            [
                'id' => Uuid::randomHex(),
                'name' => 'Demo Produkt 2',
                'price' => '29.99',
                'manufacturer' => 'Demo Hersteller 2',
            ],
            [
                'id' => Uuid::randomHex(),
                'name' => 'Demo Produkt 3',
                'price' => '39.99',
                'manufacturer' => 'Demo Hersteller 3',
            ],
        ];
    
        $data->setListing($demoProducts);
    }

}

In my javascript file for the component is use as a slot "content: 'product-test'"
In my service.xml i register my resolver with the tag "shopware.cms.data_resolver"
If i copy code from other shopware standard cms resolver and rename the type, the issue also occured. Has anyone also had this error and can give me a solution or does the issue sound familiar?
i try to read the documentation, copy code from the standard, nothing works

The solution of the error is the follwing
add
computed: {
    assetFilter() {
        return Shopware.Filter.getByName('asset');
    },

and rename and image to assetFilter(path)
<img
                :src="assetFilter('/administration/static/img/cms/preview_mountain_small.jpg')"
                alt=""
            >

